# tensorboard won't show structure (beginner trying to do LSTM's)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard, tflearn

So I'm trying to create a LSTM using Tensorflow. Unfortunately I don't really know Python, so I have been having a hard time with even the easiest stuff. I tried to make the simplest LSTM I could (code below) to start with, but when I run it and open TensorBoard, the structure page is empty (it does load, but gives me an empty page). Please see if you can understand why?

```
net = tflearn.input_data([None,226, 28])

net = tflearn.lstm(net, 38, name="Layer1")

net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='softmax', name="Layer2")

net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam',loss='mean_square')

model = tflearn.DNN(net,  tensorboard_verbose=1,tensorboard_dir='C:\\JAK 
C\\jak c\\werk\\Swot\\main\\Skripsie\\test\\tflearnlogs')
model.fit(seq,res, show_metric=True,batch_size=1,n_epoch=100)


tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to see tensor-board visualization then you have to save the graph in the log directory
- Even if you do not store the graph then obviously tensor-board will run without error but it will show you an empty web page... in the empty page it will either ask you to load the model file or will have the link to tensorflow's tensorboard tutorial page
- I think you have to add this line `model.save('my_model.tflearn')`
- You have to also write your graph with FileWriter object `writer.add_graph(sess.graph)`
- And then run the tensorboard on you browser by running the tensorboard command in your terminal which is `tensorboard --logdir=/path_to_the_log_directory`